# Which versions of the Facebook iOS SDK will stop working on October 1, 2011?

Tags: ios, migration, facebook-ios-sdk

On the [OAuth 2.0 and HTTPS Migration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/) page it says that "old iOS SDK (facebook-iphone-sdk)" will stop working on October 1. But what about older versions of the new iOS SDK (facebook-ios-sdk)? Will all old versions of facebook-ios-sdk continue to work or will versions older than a certain point stop working? I need to know whether an app using a certain version of facebook-ios-sdk needs to release a new version to address this or not.

Comment: Did u get any solution for this? i have same problem.